# How to access variable from NSObject class?

Tags: ios, swift, class, nsobject

I'm trying to learn mvc design pattern in swift. So I made the model class named User like below :

```
class User: NSObject {

var email : String!
var password : String!
var profilePictureUrl : String!

init(email: String, password: String, profilePictureUrl: String) {
    super.init()

    self.email = email
    self.password = password
    self.profilePictureUrl = profilePictureUrl
}}
```

and I'm using another class that store the function named loginConnection:

```
class loginConnection: NSObject {

class func loginUserWithEmailPassword(email: String,password: String) -> User{

    return User(email: email, password: password, profilePictureUrl: "nil")

}}
```

And I try to set and get the email,password, and profilePictureUrl from my loginViewController but I always get nil when I print the User object.

```
var userObj : User!

@IBAction func loginAction(sender: UIButton) {

    if userEmailTextField.text?.isEmpty != nil && userPasswordTextField.text?.isEmpty != nil{

        loginConnection.loginUserWithEmailPassword(userEmailTextField.text!, password:userPasswordTextField.text!)

    }
}

@IBAction func registerAction(sender: UIButton) {

    print("\(userObj.email) >>>>> \(userObj.password)")

}
```

How can I access variable from User class?

Comment: Where's the code that assigns a value to `userObj`?

Comment: I kind of confused on how to call User from my viewcontroller

Comment: @EgaSetyaPutra Why dont you try below answers. I can see Hitendra and bhoomi answered correctly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Change your `loginAction` method as below,**

```
@IBAction func loginAction(sender: UIButton) {

if userEmailTextField.text?.isEmpty == false && userPasswordTextField.text?.isEmpty == false {

    self.userObj = loginConnection.loginUserWithEmailPassword(userEmailTextField.text!, password:userPasswordTextField.text!)

    print("\(userObj.email) >>>>> \(userObj.password)")
   }
}
```

**1)** you were comparing `userEmailTextField.text?.isEmpty` with `nil`, `isEmpty` returns `Bool` value.

**2)** you were not assigning value of type `User` returned by the function `loginUserWithEmailPassword`.

Comment: loginUserWithEmailPassword is assigning the value to the user, because when I print it form inside User object the variable is not nil. I just need to access it the right way

Comment: can you let me know what is the code of your "loginAction" right now ?

Comment: Values were available at in User class, because we are passing to its "loginUserWithEmailPassword", but the object generated after "loginUserWithEmailPassword" was not saved at view controller level, so return value of "loginUserWithEmailPassword" have to be save in self.userObj,  

self.userObj = loginConnection.loginUserWithEmailPassword(userEmailTextField.text!, password:userPasswordTextField.text!)

Comment: if you store the return value in userObj at view controller level, it will available in viewController

Comment: Why can I just access the return value that already in User class?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100007/discussion-between-hitendra-hckr-and-ega-setya-putra).

Answer (score 0):

so then you have to do the following:-

```
var userObj : User = User()

userObj = loginConnection.loginUserWithEmailPassword(userEmailTextField.text!, password:userPasswordTextField.text!)
```

after that

```
userObj.email
```

Comment: Why post a 2nd answer? Why not just fix the original answer? Delete one of them at least.

Comment: that will ruin the mvc pattern

Comment: Dear

First you have to allocate memory to userObj

then you can assign value from loginConnection.loginUserWithEmailPassword

I don't think it is going to ruin MVC

Comment: but it will not be efficient since I already have the function in loginConnection that return to User object

Answer (score 0):

Are you calling userObj from loginAction?
Like Below..

```
var userObj : User!

@IBAction func loginAction(sender: UIButton) {

if userEmailTextField.text?.isEmpty != nil && userPasswordTextField.text?.isEmpty != nil{

    userObj = loginConnection.loginUserWithEmailPassword(userEmailTextField.text!, password:userPasswordTextField.text!)

    print("\(userObj.email) >>>>> \(userObj.password)")
   }
}
```

loginUserWithEmailPassword return User class object so you can use that to access User class properties

Comment: I already use the loginConnection.loginUserWithEmailPassword to return the value to the User object. What I need is just how can I access it from my view controller? because if print the variable in User init the value is not nil

Comment: so you want like if i am not call loginUserWithEmailPassword and though i want to access userObj?Do you mean these?

Comment: Exactly what you want to do can you just give some brief explain?So i can help you in deep.

Comment: my problem is when I call User object like in my code right now, the varibale of User object will become nil

Comment: but if I print the variable inside the User object it has the value ,since I already return the value from loginConnection

Comment: so What I need is how to access the User object without nil value

Comment: yes it will be nil because see you don't assign any value to User object and you can that only get from loginConnection.loginUserWithEmailPassword.Because it only return value.

Comment: At start you have only do assignment.Have you give value at assignment?No, you haven't assign so it will be always nil.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100005/discussion-between-bhoomi-and-ega-setya-putra).

Answer (score 0):

I can't see why this needs to be an NSObject. By making it a struct you can remove the init since it will come automatically. Also remove the ! in most cases since it quite dangerous to use implicitly unwrapped optionals unless you know what you're doing. Xcode will also help with the autocompletion and give good suggestions on how to fix as you go. If you do this you'll find the compiler tell you about the problems before run time errors can happen.

Comment: While this may be good information it has nothing to do with the problem in the question. Please update your answer by trying to answer the actual question. Leave the current info as extra details at the end of your answer.

Answer (score 0):

You declared userObj instance of User but you didn't assigned it by the values will return from loginUserWithEmailPassword function.

Assign you userObj as below in your viewController loginAction.

```
@IBAction func loginAction(sender: UIButton) {

        userObj = loginConnection.loginUserWithEmailPassword("Karan", password:"karanPassword")
        self.registerAction()
    }
```

Now you will get the assigned username and password.

```
@IBAction func registerAction(sender: UIButton) {

        print("\(userObj.email) >>>>> \(userObj.password)")

    }
```

Here I got the username and password on my output window
[image]